# Writing drivers for a NIC from a datasheet

Tags: linux, driver, broadcom

I am interested in writing a driver for the Broadcom BCM4330 chip for Linux, however
the datasheet for it does not give me any information on the VENDOR_ID or DEVICE_ID nor any technical information on physical addresses of the chip.

How would one go about writing it?